# MATLAB how to skip first line

Tags: matlab

```
fid = fopen('uncon_fat2_slowness.txt','r');
A = textscan(fid,'%f%f','Delimiter',',','headerLines',1);
data = cat(2,A{:});
```

But

```
 A

A = 

    [0x1 double]    [0x1 double]

>> data = cat(2,A{:});
>> data

data =

   Empty matrix: 0-by-2
```

My file has 2000 lines after the header,how to read this properly?

```
#"DensityScaled","Density"
 -5.610522610822E-03 -5.610522610822E-03
 -5.622053005619E-03 -5.622053005619E-03
 -5.646903768966E-03 -5.646903768966E-03
 -5.684320728827E-03 -5.684320728827E-03
```

Comment: This works fine on my computer. Are you sure this example reproduces the issue?

Comment: @excaza Yes,works fine now,I do not know what happened!